# cakePHP 3 migration issue

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, data-migration

I made a migration script in cakephp and ran the script using the command
"bin/cake migrations migrate"

my code in the up() function:

```
$preparedArray=[
  'name'=>'dhruv',
  'surname'=>'sharma'
];
$table = $this->table('name');
$table->insert($preparedArray);
$table->saveData();
```

when I run the command, i get a fatal error:- "uncaught type error Argument 1 passed to Cake\Console\ConsoleErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Err
or given in C:-- Projects --\myproject\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\
ConsoleErrorHandler.php:64"

I am using cakePHP 3.0.6 and php 7.0.4

Kindly help

Comment: The [CakePHP/3 release notes](https://bakery.cakephp.org/2015/03/22/CakePHP-3-0-0-is-Here.html) do not even mention PHP/7. I suspect it's just not supported. You may need to upgrade to something newer like 3.4.

Comment: @ndm Does the 3.0.x branch support PHP/7? It looks like a problem with CakePHP internals, not something the user can fix.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Depends on how you look at it I guess. AFAIK it generally works with PHP7, but didn't claimed 100% compatibility. The `Error` handling problem has only been fixed as of `3.1.5`, which was the last PHP7 incompatibilty at that point, and if I'm not mistaken, full PHP7 compatibility has been claimed as of then.

Comment: @ndm Sorry, I reopened the question inadvertently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i do not have cakephp3 installed computer with me so i can not check the file which is throwing exception.
I will suggest you to try this in up function 
//assuming Names is your table
    `$namesTable = TableRegistry::get('Names');`
     `$name = $namesTable->newEntity();` 
    `$name->name = 'dhruv';`
    `$name->surname = 'sharma';`
    `$namesTable->save($name);`